# How can I create a default deployment stage in API Gateway using Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, terraform, aws-api-gateway

I have an API Gateway setup using Terraform. I need to be able to visit the API Gateway on the base path, i.e, without the stage name appended to the base URL.

`https://{api_id}.execute-api.{region}.amazonaws.com/` <- acceptable

`https://{api_id}.execute-api.{region}.amazonaws.com/{StageName}` <- not acceptable

I would do this from the console by creating a [default deployment stage like here.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-stages.html)

I looked but could not find anything in the terraform documentation [here for stages](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/api_gateway_stage)

I want to be able to do this by creating the default stage, not using a [aws_api_gateway_domain_name](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/api_gateway_domain_name) resource

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-stages.html):

> You can create a `$default` stage that is served from the base of your API's URL—for example, `https://{api_id}.execute-api.{region}.amazonaws.com/`. You use this URL to invoke an API stage.

The Terraform documentation doesn't mention this, but you can create a stage with `$default` as the stage name. Calling the base path should then use that stage.

```
resource "aws_apigatewayv2_stage" "example" {
  api_id = aws_apigatewayv2_api.example.id
  name   = "$default"
}
```

Comment: Note that this is only available for the HTTP version of the API Gateway.  It's not supported by the REST version.

Answer (score 4):

`aws_api_gateway_domain_name` is for [REST API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-rest-api.html) which does not have a default stage. To create such a stage you **have to use** [HTTP API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api.html) which in terraform is provided by the family of [apigatewayv2](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/apigatewayv2_api) methods.